# How to sync highlights & annotations of ebooks/pdf

Tags: sync, ebook-reader, ebooks

i'm searching for a way to synchronize  highlights & annotations of my ebooks over several android devices.

I prefer to read ebooks in pdf as it's the only format that keeps the original layout of the book.

Moonreader+ is a good ebook reader that supports highlighting and syncing reading progress. But how can i sync highlights or annotations i made?

Comment: I can't imagine how this would be implemented, especially since you also need to make sure that the PDFs exist. How do you check that file.pdf in Device A is the same as file.pdf in Device B? Unlike in Kindle, you know which book is which, and highlights can actually be synced. But what you want is certainly possible though, if you make a custom app, with lots of assumptions here and there.

Comment: Moon+ could do that as well, but it will be limited when it comes to PDF. Annotations/Highlights can be *exported* to files which you then could sync and *import* at the other end. I'm not aware of any automatism here; but I wouldn't wonder you'll find it in the next version if you ask Seany (the dev) for it, as he's very responsive usually.